# Kendo dataSource offline __state__ property not removed after update

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using the offline support of Kendo dataSource. It's kinda' working, in that I can make changes whilst the dataSource is offline and these are sent to the server when a connection is established.

However, the `__state__: "update"` property is not removed after posting the changed record to the server. This is resulting in the same update being posted to the server multiple times if the dataSource switches between online/offline modes.

I've tried returning the same data as a confirmation of the successful save operation, and I've also tried returning an empty response (as suggested in the documents).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new `dataSource` with the same data after `window.navigator.onLine` as a workaround?

Comment: You could open an issue on their [github page](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues).